# Way to re-run the program automatically if kernel dies in python?

Tags: python, automation, kernel

I have a particular method which calculates the distances between the points in the dataset and unfortunately during the process the kernel dies. So I wrote the code(in Python) in such a way that it starts calculating the distance from the point where it stopped instead of calculating from scratch. So whenever the kernel dies I am rerunning the program manually but is there any way to make it re run automatically without my presence ???

Would be glad if share some information or method of doing it...
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: More details please. What computer is the script running on (yours or an external cluster)? Is the kernel crash related to your process?

Comment: I am running on my personal computer and working on jupyter notebook. during the distance calculation process the ram is completely occupied with the variables. When there is no space in the RAM, the kernel is dying and the RAM is getting completly free.

Comment: As you may find in the tag's description, the "kernel" tag is about **Operating System**'s kernel. But your question is definitely not about Operating System. Please, choose more appropriate tag. Am not very familiar with a "kernel in Python", so I cannot suggest the correct tag. But "kernel" tag is definitely wrong.